# How to prevent form submission for a form using onchange to submit the form when certain values are selected

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, onchange

I have a form I have built:

```
<form class="myform" action="cgi.pl">
  <select name="export" onchange='this.form.submit()'> 
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose an export format</option> 
    <option value="html">HTML</option> 
    <option value="csv">CSV</option> 
  </select>
</form>
```

Now, this form works fine if I pull down and select "HTML" or "CSV". But if I hit the back button and select "Choose an export format", the form is submitted, even though I dont want it to be.

Is there any way to prevent form submission for that option?

Answer (score 4):

```
onchange='if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value!=''){ this.form.submit(); }'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select[name=export]").on("change", function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $("form.myform").submit();
      }
});
```